# Unable to display the data by using useEffect hook inside MaterialTable

Tags: reactjs, components, material-ui, react-hooks

```
import React,{useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';
import axios from 'axios';

// function for adding the 
export default function MaterialTableDemo() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    columns: [
      { title: 'Id', field: 'Id' },
      { title: 'Todo', field: 'Todo' },
      { title: 'Description', field: 'Description', type: 'numeric' },
    ],
    data: [],
  });

  // get the state here   
  useEffect(()=>{
     axios.get('http://localhost:4000/todos').then((res)=>{
          {console.log(res.data)}
          state.data = res.data
          {console.log(state)}
     })
  })

  return (
    <MaterialTable
      title="Todo Example"
      columns={state.columns}
      data={state.data}
      />

  );
```

}

1)  {console.log(state)} is printing the following data inside useEffect hook

```
{columns: Array(3), data: Array(7)}
columns: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
data: (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
__proto__: Object
```

2) Inside my Material Table No data is shown ,i don't why ? but i could see my column names

3) My backed api is working i am getting the response

4) i don't know,  what is causing the error  whether the async nature  or usage  of hook

5) my page is continuous sending request to the api how to make it work as componentdid mount()

Comment: `{console.log(res.data)}` what is this line printing?

Comment: Array(7)
0: {_id: "5e6768a42c21f17e9da41e72", todo: "hello mdvenkatesh", descripion: "you are great", __v: 0}
1: {_id: "5e67690272c1388a58925030", todo: "hello mdvenkatesh", descripion: "you are great", __v: 0}
2: {_id: "5e676cba12e090b87466a872", todo: "hello mdvenkatesh", descripion: "you are great", __v: 0}
3: {_id: "5e676d5564b8d61eb98bf78b", todo: "hello mdvenkatesh", descripion: "you are great", __v: 0}
5: {_id: "5e676f1fd2368fe5c42ec25a", todo: "hello mdvenkatesh", descripion: "you are great", __v: 0}
length: 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`field` attribute (key) in `columns` prop should match the attributes (keys) in the `data` props. For Example:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    columns: [
      { title: "Name", field: "name" },
      { title: "Surname", field: "surname" }
    ],
    data: [{ name: "Zain", surname: "Ul Abideen" }]
  });
  return (
    <MaterialTable
      title="Todo Example"
      columns={state.columns}
      data={state.data}
    />
  );
}
```

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-field-045sc)

**Tip:**

Correct way to set the state is:

```
  useEffect(()=>{
     axios.get('http://localhost:4000/todos').then((res)=>{
          {console.log(res.data)}
          setState({
            ...state,
            data: {...state.data, res.data}
          })
          {console.log(state)}
     })
  }, []) // Empty array brackets means you want only one time your component to do the things mentioned in `useEffect`, Brief [guide][2].
```

`state.data = res.data` creates shallow copy of the data not deep copy. here is an [article](https://we-are.bookmyshow.com/understanding-deep-and-shallow-copy-in-javascript-13438bad941c) to understand it further.

Comment: Thanks ,

field names should match the  key values from backend  but  my page is continuous sending request to the api how to make it work as componentdid mount

Comment: I got "." (comma) expected error from data: {...state.data, res.data} the error points to dot "."

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  useEffect(()=>{
     axios.get('http://localhost:4000/todos').then((res)=>{
          {console.log(res.data)}
          setState({
            ...state,
            data: res.data,
          });
          {console.log(state)}
     })
  })
```

Comment: I canot see the data but  no of lines inside are equal to the length of data  moreever perfermonce issue every time it is calling the api